# Except for speed and resource usage, are there any other criteria that two algorithms can compete about?

Tags: testing, evaluation, experimental-design

I intend to race two algorithms and evaluate them. Ignoring developer hindrances such as complexity and deployment difficulties, are there any other criteria which I can test the algorithms against?

- By **speed** I mean the fastest algorithm to return a successful
  result.
- By **resources** I mean computational power, memory and storage.

Please note that the algorithms in questions are in fact genetic algorithms. Precisely, a parallel genetic algorithm over a distributed network against a local non-distributed genetic algorithm. So results will differ with each run.

Comment: completeness, robustness about every possible input vector (stack overflow,...), maintainability, any coding standard complient, portablity to several hardware

Answer (score 0):

Further criteria might be:
- influence of compiler / optimisation flags
- cpu architecture dependence

For speed you should keep in mind that is can vary from run to run. Often the first is the slowest. A meassure like average of fastest 3 execution time from 10000 might help.

Comment: thanks. I should probably mention that these algorithms are in fact genetic algorithms.